# vim terminal scrolls slower than gVim

Tags: windows, performance, vim, scroll

I use vim 7.4 on Windows 10. I noticed that vim (terminal version) renders much slower that gvim. It's visible best when scrolling buffer with keyboard on large screen. Is it possible to improve the experience on terminal version?

Comment: You meant scrolling more lines at a time? Then, you can try mapping Or, if ou want to refresh the screen, you can redraw it. Which one you want ?

Comment: What commands do you use for scrolling?

Comment: Scrolling just one line is enough to see the effect. When the cursor is in the last line visible and I press "j" then the screen needs to be scrolled down. It redraws much slower in vim terminal than gVim.

Comment: `j` isn't for scrolling. Anyway, redrawing has always been slower in terminal than in GVim.